# Filter explicit images in google api

Tags: google-search-api, google-image-search

Hi i want to filter the explicit images when i run my application(in local and server).
     how to i restrict the images which are containing adult images what should i do for restrict images using google custom search engine please anyone help me.

i am using below code but its not working.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


        google.load('search', '1');

        function initialize() {

            var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();          
            searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.ImageSearch());
            searchControl.draw(document.getElementById("searchcontrol"));
            searchControl.execute("sunset");
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: What has this to do with appengine?  This is client javascript code and is consuming google search service which has nothing to do with appegine.

Comment: i want to implement safe search filteration-ON in my application once it is published on server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code [from this guide](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/reference)

var searcher = new google.search.ImageSearch();
searcher.setRestriction(
     google.search.Search.RESTRICT_SAFESEARCH,
     google.search.Search.SAFESEARCH_STRICT);

imageSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback ...
 imageSearch.execute....

Also notice:

1. Adult filtering works only for few languages ([please see it here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=ru#safeSearchLevels))
2. This API marked as deprecated. Probably in future you should use some sort of [this API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=ru#safeSearchLevels). I am still using deprecated API, but in any time Google can disable this one.